# how to add 1:1 relationship to plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Consider this example:

```
x = [99.125,98.041;...
     85.125,83.791;...
     93.625,94.583;...
     76.125,76.833;...
     80.416,81.166;...
     82.458,87.541;...
     84.500,83.291;...
     75.916,77.208];

scatter(x(:,1),x(:,2))
```

I can plot the line of best fit with

```
lsline
```

but how do I plot the 1:1 relationship line instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "1:1 relationship" you mean the map implicitly defined by the two columns of `x`, you could plot it as follows.

```
x_s = sortrows(x, 1)
plot(x_s(:,1), x_s(:,2))
```

[image]